# Bootstrap Popover Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap, and I am trying to make a popover appear from clicking a button element. As far as I can tell I initialized bootstrap and the popover element correctly, but the popup element does not appear when I click my button.

I also do not see any errors or info in the console when I click the button, but the button itself gets a border around it when I click it which makes me think that the popover function is doing something and applying at least the bootstrap styles.

Here is my jQuery and Bootstrap initialization:

```
<!---JQuery Iniialization --->
<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"/>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery/libs/jqueryui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<!---Bootstrap Iniialization --->   
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Here are my html elements and javascript function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover() ;
    });
</script>
                        
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-2" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" title="Details" data-trigger="focus" title="Details" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
<i class="fa-light fa-memo-circle-info"></i></button>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

i added this cdn and it worked

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That has no effect for me.